# Is it allowed to record CommandBuffers on multiple threads which were allocated from the same pool?

Tags: vulkan

Suppose we have a CommandPool with two CommandBuffers allocated from it (`CommandBuffer1`, `CommandBuffer2`).

The CommandPool lives on `Thread 0`, `CommandBuffer1` and `CommandBuffer2` also live on `Thread 0`.

Is it possible to transfer `CommandBuffer1` and `CommandBuffer1` to a different thread to record commands? With the restriction that only one thread is allowed the record a CommandBuffer at the same time?

The spec states

> Command pools are application-synchronized, meaning that a command pool must not be used concurrently in multiple threads. **That includes use via recording commands on any command buffers allocated from the pool**, as well as operations that allocate, free, and reset command buffers or the pool itself.

I am not quite sure if I would be allowed to record `CommandBuffer1` on `Thread 1` and `CommandBuffer2` on `Thread 2` at the same time.

Or do I have to record all CommandBuffers on the same thread that they were allocated from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a list of "Implicit Externally Synchronized Parameters" in chapter 2.5. Threading Behavior that has a list mostly consisting of:

> - The VkCommandPool that commandBuffer was allocated from, in vkCmd*

So no it's not possible to record 2 command buffers from the same pool on different threads.

Though it is strange that `vkBeginCommandBuffer` and `vkEndCommandBuffer` isn't in that list.

Answer (score 2):

Who's forcing you to have only one pool though?
Have one pool per thread. Problem solved.

Yes, you do not have to use them on the same thread. You just **must** make sure that:

> [...]command pool must not be used concurrently in multiple threads.

If you (for some obscure reason) want to use the pool on different thread, you must stop using it on the original thread (via using synchronization primitives) before you start using it on the second thread.